# Is a root system determined by the choice of an invariant lattice?

Tags: root-systems

Let $\Phi$ be a root system in a real vector space $V$, and let $W = W(\Phi)$ denote its Weyl group, and let $Q = Q(\Phi) \subseteq P = P(\Phi) \subseteq V$ denote the root and weight sublattices. Moreover, let $X$ denote a $W$-invariant sublattice

$$Q \subseteq X \subseteq P$$

Is is then true that $X$ determines $\Phi$ in the sense that if $\Phi' \subseteq V$ is another root system with

$$W = W(\Phi')\quad\text{and}\quad Q(\Phi') \subseteq X \subseteq P(\Phi')$$

, then $\Phi' = \Phi$?

Comment: The standard realization of $B_n$ has root lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$, while the standard realization of $C_n$ has weight lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$, so you won’t be able to tell these apart (and they have the same Weyl group). So it looks like the answer to your question is no.